# Синхронизация структуры JSON-файлов конфигурации в .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Частая проблема, когда во время разработки структура локального **secrets.json** меняется, а **appsettings.json** - нет (по забывчивости и невнимательности).

Какие есть варианты предотвращать такие ошибки? Осложнение в том, что **secrets.json** никак не относится к структуре и иерархии проекта, а берётся просто по ссылке.

Comment: Полагаю, это можно (и нужно) отслеживать в рамках интеграционного тестирования.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну это понятно, хотелось бы контроль автоматизировать. Тесты писать для этого предлагаете?

Comment: Один раз пишем тест - далее проверка выполняется автоматически.